# Does F2FS support permissions and symlinks?

Tags: filesystems, f2fs

Just wondering before I do the migration from EXT4 to F2FS for my Raspberry Pi setup.  Does F2FS support permissions and symlinks?

https://github.com/Fourdee/DietPi/issues/606#issuecomment-260327177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS), it supports POSIX attributes, permissions and file types. It was designed for use with Linux.